# How can I use BERT to generate a long paragraph?

Tags: lstm, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, transformer-model, mlp

I am trying to write an image-capturing model, use the CNN model to extract the image feature, and then connect with BERT and MLP to generate a long paragraph However, after training, my model result is really bad. In my MLP part, I should add LSTM into the different feature and then concatenate them, but I don't know where should I add it. Anyone can give me some advice? Thank you!

My BERT decoder part:

```
class bert_decoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

def __init__(self, vocab_size, embed_dim, max_len):
    super().__init__()
    self.bert_model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased", trainable=False)
    self.ffn_layer1 =  keras.layers.Dense(1000)
    self.ffn_layer2 = keras.layers.Dense(EMBEDDING_DIM * (max_len - 1))
    self.flatten = keras.layers.Flatten()
    self.reshape = keras.layers.Reshape((max_len - 1, embed_dim))
def call(self, input_ids):

    bert_out = self.bert_model(input_ids)[0]
    bert_out_flatten = self.flatten(bert_out)
    bert_out = self.ffn_layer1(bert_out_flatten)
    bert_out = self.ffn_layer2(bert_out)
    bert_out = self.reshape(bert_out)
    return bert_out
```

My MLP part:

```
class TransformerDecoderLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

def __init__(self, embed_dim, units, num_heads):
    super().__init__()
    self.embedding = bert_decoder(
        tokenizer.vocabulary_size(), embed_dim, MAX_LENGTH)

    self.attention_1 = tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(
        num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim, dropout=0.1
    )
    self.attention_2 = tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(
        num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim, dropout=0.1
    )

    self.layernorm_1 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization()
    self.layernorm_2 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization()
    self.layernorm_3 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization()

    self.ffn_layer_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, activation="relu")
    self.ffn_layer_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(embed_dim)

    self.out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(tokenizer.vocabulary_size(), activation="softmax")

    self.dropout_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)
    self.dropout_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)


def call(self, input_ids, encoder_output, training, mask=None):

    embeddings = self.embedding(input_ids)
    
    combined_mask = None
    padding_mask = None
    if mask is not None:
        causal_mask = self.get_causal_attention_mask(embeddings)
        padding_mask = tf.cast(mask[:, :, tf.newaxis], dtype=tf.int32)
        combined_mask = tf.cast(mask[:, tf.newaxis, :], dtype=tf.int32)
        combined_mask = tf.minimum(combined_mask, causal_mask)
    
    attn_output_1 = self.attention_1(
        query=embeddings,
        value=embeddings,
        key=embeddings,
        attention_mask=combined_mask,
        training=training
    )
    
    out_1 = self.layernorm_1(embeddings + attn_output_1)

    attn_output_2 = self.attention_2(
        query=out_1,
        value=encoder_output,
        key=encoder_output,
        attention_mask=padding_mask,
        training=training
    )

    out_2 = self.layernorm_2(out_1 + attn_output_2)

    ffn_out = self.ffn_layer_1(out_2)
    ffn_out = self.dropout_1(ffn_out, training=training)
    ffn_out = self.ffn_layer_2(ffn_out)

    ffn_out = self.layernorm_3(ffn_out + out_2)
    ffn_out = self.dropout_2(ffn_out, training=training)
    preds = self.out(ffn_out)
    return preds


def get_causal_attention_mask(self, inputs):
    input_shape = tf.shape(inputs)
    batch_size, sequence_length = input_shape[0], input_shape[1]
    i = tf.range(sequence_length)[:, tf.newaxis]
    j = tf.range(sequence_length)
    mask = tf.cast(i >= j, dtype="int32")
    mask = tf.reshape(mask, (1, input_shape[1], input_shape[1]))
    mult = tf.concat(
        [tf.expand_dims(batch_size, -1), tf.constant([1, 1], dtype=tf.int32)],
        axis=0
    )
    return tf.tile(mask, mult)
```